# Not getting singletons using Dagger

Tags: java, android, singleton, dagger

I am just getting started with Dagger in my current Android app, and I'm not sure how to achieve the functionality I'm looking for (I believe what I'm looking for *is* possible).

Basically, my situation is this.  I have the following classes I want to have their instances/injections managed by Dagger.  I also want some of these to be singletons, which are noted by (1):

- CipherFactory - simple, package-private factory

  CryptoService (1) - has a dependency on CipherFactory

  SerializationService (1) - has a dependency on Jackson's ObjectMapper

  PlayerApplicationService (1) - has a dependency on SerializationService

  PlayerRepository (1) - has dependencies on SerializationService, CryptoService

Now, I can get Dagger to create these services and appropriately inject their dependencies just fine; the issue is that some classes have a dependency on more than one class and it appears through logging statements I'm getting *new* instances each time it gets injected.

Here is what I currently have for the above, including the Dagger module classes:

**CryptoService.java**

```
@Singleton
public class CryptoService {
    private final CipherFactory cipherFactory;

    @Inject
    CryptoService(CipherFactory cipherFactory) {
        this.cipherFactory = cipherFactory;
    }
    ...
}
```

**CryptoServiceModule.java**

```
@Module(
        injects = CryptoService.class,
        complete = true,
        library = true
)
public class CryptoServiceModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    CipherFactory provideCipher() {
        return new CipherFactory();
    }

}
```

**SerializationService.java**

```
@Singleton
public class SerializationService {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    SerializationService(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    ...
}
```

**SerializationServiceModule.java**

```
@Module(
        injects = SerializationService.class,
        library = true,
        complete = true
)
public class SerializationServiceModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ObjectMapper provideMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

**PlayerApplicationService.java**

```
public class PlayerApplicationService {

    private SerializationService serializationService;

    @Inject
    public PlayerApplicationService(SerializationService serializationService) {
        this.serializationService = serializationService;
    }
    ....
}
```

**PlayerApplicationServiceModule.java**

```
@Module(
        injects = PlayerApplicationService.class,
        includes = {
                SerializationServiceModule.class
        },
        complete = true,
        library = true
)
public class PlayerApplicationServiceModule {
}
```

**PlayerRepository.java**

```
@Singleton
public class PlayerRepository implements Repository<Player> {

    private final SerializationService serializationService;
    private final CryptoService cryptoService;

    @Inject
    public PlayerRepository(SerializationService serializationService, CryptoService cryptoService) {
        this.serializationService = serializationService;
        this.cryptoService = cryptoService;
    }
    ...
}
```

**PlayerRepositoryModule.java**

```
@Module(
        injects = PlayerRepository.class,
        includes = {
                SerializationServiceModule.class,
                CryptoServiceModule.class
        },
        complete = true,
        library = true
)
public class PlayerRepositoryModule {
}
```

What am I missing?  As I mentioned above, all of this stuff *works* as is, it just looks like I'm getting multiple instances of some dependencies (`SerializationService`, for example, which is used by two classes) created where I only want/need one.

Comment: I would suggest you to combine all modules into one big module that inject to all classes. I suspect that SerializationServiceModule is being created twice. For example, SerializationServiceModule.java create an ObjectMapper, then PlayerRepositoryModule.java creates another ObjectMapper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that works.  I posted my answer below based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Andyccs, I've consolidated everything into an application-level Module class and removed all other Module classes in the application:

**PlayerApplicationModule.java**

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                PlayerApplication.class,
                CryptoService.class,
                SerializationService.class,
                PlayerApplicationService.class
        },
        complete = true,
        library = true
)
public class PlayerApplicationModule {
    private PlayerApplication application;

    public PlayerApplicationModule(PlayerApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CipherFactory provideCipherFactory() {
        return new CipherFactory();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

Everything is now working as expected.